# Changing Field Type of a column

Tags: column, site-column, spfield, field-type

Is it possible to change Field Type of a column from TaxonomyField to Single Line of Text? It is a SharePoint online solution.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible with code? I'm assuming you've tried to change it through the browser and/or Designer, which both would've told you that it's not possible.

Comment: No it is not possible, I thought maybe there is a way to do it.